# Simultaneous write operations using runTransaction method in Firestore not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a flutter application in which feedbacks can be taken. So, I need to handle multiple form submissions at once. I'm using runTransaction method provided in firestore to handle that. But, when I try to submit a feedback form simultaneously from two devices, a response from only one device is being recorded.

It's mentioned in the documentation that runTransaction method retries the transaction if any of the clients modify a document. But, that's not happening in my case. How do I solve the issue?

Here's the code that I've written.

```
uploadFeedback(context) {
    ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pr.style(message: 'Submitting response');
    pr.show();
    var ref = Firestore.instance.collection('/feedbacks').document(widget.data);
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      // Read operation
      var doc = await ref.get();
      var prev = doc['scores'];
      attended = doc['attended'];
      attended.add(email);
      for (int i = 0; i < questionObjectList.length; i++) {
        int response = questionObjectList[i].response;
        prev[i.toString()][response - 1] += 1;
      }
      updated = prev;

      // Update operation
      return transaction.update(ref, {
        'scores': updated,
        'attended': attended
      });
    }).then((val) {
      pr.hide();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Feedback submitted successfully');
    }).catchError((e) {
      pr.hide();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Some error occured');
      throw Error();
    });
  }
```

Also attaching the code of the entire file

```
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:feedback_system/public/Metrics/effort_rating.dart';
import 'package:feedback_system/public/Metrics/goalcompletionrate_meter.dart';
import 'package:feedback_system/public/Metrics/questionandresponse.dart';
import 'package:feedback_system/public/Metrics/satisfaction_rating.dart';
import 'package:feedback_system/public/Metrics/smiley_rating.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Answer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;

  Answer({this.data});

  @override
  _AnswerState createState() => _AnswerState();
}

class _AnswerState extends State<Answer> {
  var data;
  double avg = 0;
  var attended;
  bool perform = false;
  String email;
  var updated;
  var _doc;
  List<QuestionAndResponse> questionObjectList =
      new List<QuestionAndResponse>();

  instantiate() async {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('/feedbacks')
        .document(widget.data)
        .get()
        .then((_data) {
      if (!_data.exists) {
        setState(() {
          data = 'Error';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          data = _data;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  getSharedPreferences() async {
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((val) {
      setState(() {
        email = val.getString("email");
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSharedPreferences();
    instantiate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    if (data == null)
      return SpinKitThreeBounce(color: Colors.blue);
    else if (data == 'Error')
      return stopUser('Feedback no longer exists');
    else if (data['attended'].contains(email))
      return stopUser('Can\'t give feedback more than once');
    else
      return fetchDocument(width);
  }

  stopUser(data) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Text(data),
    ));
  }

  fetchDocument(double width) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(data['name']),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
            Divider(height: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == data['questions'].length) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Color(0xff23272B),
                child: Text(
                  'Submit',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  uploadFeedback(context);
                },
              ),
            );
          }
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 2, 5, 2),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  leading: Text(
                    (index + 1).toString() + ")",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    data['questions'][index],
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                metric(index)
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: data['questions'].length + 1,
      ),
    );
  }

  metric(int index) {
    switch (data['metrics'][index]) {
      case 'Satisfaction':
        return slider(index);
      case 'SmileyRating':
        return smiley(index);
      case 'EffortScore':
        return effortScore(index);
      case 'GoalCompletionRate':
        return goalCompletionRate(index);
      default:
        return Text('Unexpected error');
    }
  }

  goalCompletionRate(int index) {
    QuestionAndResponse temp =
        QuestionAndResponse(data['questions'][index], "GoalCompletionRate");
    questionObjectList.add(temp);
    return GoalCompletionRateMeter(temp);
  }

  effortScore(int index) {
    QuestionAndResponse temp =
        QuestionAndResponse(data['questions'][index], "EffortScore");
    questionObjectList.add(temp);
    return EffortRatingMeter(temp);
  }

  smiley(int index) {
    QuestionAndResponse temp =
        QuestionAndResponse(data['questions'][index], "SmileyRating");
    questionObjectList.add(temp);
    return SmileyRatingMeter(temp);
  }

  slider(int index) {
    QuestionAndResponse temp =
        QuestionAndResponse(data['questions'][index], "Satisfaction");
    questionObjectList.add(temp);
    return SatisafactionRatingMeter(temp);
  }

  uploadFeedback(context) {
    ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pr.style(message: 'Submitting response');
    pr.show();
    var ref = Firestore.instance.collection('/feedbacks').document(widget.data);
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      var doc = await ref.get();
      var prev = doc['scores'];
      attended = doc['attended'];
      attended.add(email);
      print(attended);
      for (int i = 0; i < questionObjectList.length; i++) {
        int response = questionObjectList[i].response;
        prev[i.toString()][response - 1] += 1;
      }
      updated = prev;

      return transaction.update(ref, {
        'scores': updated,
        'attended': attended
      });
    }).then((val) {
      pr.hide();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Feedback submitted successfully');
    }).catchError((e) {
      pr.hide();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Some error occured');
      throw Error();
    });
  }
}
```

I don't know whether I'm using runTransaction method in the correct way. Because there's no proper documentation for using Firestore in Flutter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you'll be able to simulate a collision between clients by manually operating two instances of your app.  What's probably happening is that the first transaction is completing, then the second transaction is completing and overwriting the first.  A transaction won't stop two apps from modifying the same document.  It will just ensure that they happen in order.  It's meant for things like making sure two writes that change some value (such as incrementing a value) do so in a consistent way.

Comment: What's probably happening is that the first transaction is completing, then the second transaction is completing and overwriting the first. I totally disagree with this. Because I've submitted the response from multiple devices and the database has been updated as expected. Transactions are used to perform the operations on a fresh copy of the data up to my knowledge and that's exactly what they've mentioned in the documentation

Comment: That's not the way transactions work.  There is nothing "fresh" about the data in the transaction.  It's the same as what the previous client left there.  There is only a retry if another client wrote data during the time the current client was figuring out what to do with the data it just read as part of the transaction. Unless you have specific reproduction steps with actual data and details logs, it's not really possible to explain what's happening.

Comment: Actually what I meant by fresh data is nothing but the data previous client left there. As you've mentioned that there's only a retry if another client wrote data while other client is still processing the data. Yes, that's true. And that's what should happen. But the thing is that's not happening in my case. My transaction is not retrying to execute again but instead it's terminating. So I'm trying to figure out what's stopping my transaction from retrying.

Comment: How are you able to ensure that two clients are actually running the transaction as the exact same time, interleaving their access to the node of the transatction?  Again, that's **highly** unlikely to reproduce manually.